# DJI Onboard SDK to Mobile SDK communication - DJI sample not working. (Matrice 600- Raspberry Pi3 - iOS)

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, dji-sdk

I want to send commands from mobile device with the mobile-SDK to the onboard computer (Raspberry Pi 3) on the drone (Matrice 600) running the onboard-SDK. Therefore I am trying to make the sample from DJI work. I followed the guide (https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-mobile-communication.html) and the link (https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/msdk-comm.html). I used the code from https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/tree/3.8/sample/linux/mobile for onboard-SDK and the iOS sample https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-OSDK-iOS-App.

The Mobile App is saying it is sending commands but the onboard program does not recognize any and the log is not displaying any errors.

I did not change anything on the code besides my API Key I put in the variable. It says the product has been registered right. Also, the UART connection between the drone and the raspberry seems fine since every other example I tried is working. Also, the connection between the mobile device and the drone is working since other Apps like DJI-Go are able to send commands to the drone, which are then executed.

I am using the simulator on the DJI-Assistant Windows Program.

I feel like the problem is already in the App because I tried to log at different sections of the code and it seems like code that should be executed is not executed. I did not develop iOS apps so I do not really know what is going on exactly but maybe you can help me out.

For example code inside here is not executed. Does that mean he did not manage to finish "Sending"? 
From "Mobile-OSDK-iOS-App/MOS/Network/MOSProductCommunicationManager.m"

```
[fc sendDataToOnboardSDKDevice:data withCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle error locally
        } else {
            NSString *key = [self commandIDStringKeyFromData:data];

            [self.sentCmds setObject:ackBlock forKey:key];
        }
        completion(error);
    }];
```

Also in the log there are no other logs like these following up:
From "Mobile-OSDK-iOS-App/MOS/ViewController/MOSJSONDynamicController.m"

```
[self.appDelegate.model addLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sending CmdID %@ with %ld Arguments", cmdId, (unsigned long)arguments.count]];
        weakCell.commandResultLabel.text = @"Sending...";
        [self.appDelegate.productCommunicationManager sendData:data
                                                withCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                    [self.appDelegate.model addLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sent CmdID %@", cmdId]];
                                                    weakCell.commandResultLabel.text = @"Command Sent!";
                                                }
                                                   andAckBlock:^(NSData * _Nonnull data, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                                                       NSData *ackData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, [data length] - 2)];
                                                       uint16_t ackValue;
                                                       [ackData getBytes:&ackValue length:sizeof(uint16_t)];

                                                       NSString *responseMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ack: %u", ackValue];
                                                       [self.appDelegate.model addLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Received ACK [%@] for CmdID %@", responseMessage, cmdId]];

                                                       weakCell.commandResultLabel.text = responseMessage;
                                                   }];
```

Here are screenshots of the logs:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: which is the firmware version for drone and remote, whats the OSDK version and and MSDK version?? is it exactly the same firmware version stated in the osdk github? DJI internal function has a heavy correlation with firmware version. A minor change in the firmware can cause part of DJI system to not function. You can see a similar sample my post before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696909/dji-osdk-and-osdk-ros-3-7-and-3-8-bug-demo-flight-control-take-off-and-halt

Comment: I tried OSDK to MSDK message sending before in 3.3 beta. It was working. I was sending it as a beacon to indicate the onboard PC is running. If not running, MSDK will take over.  The exact version of firmware I can not remember, I do remmeber we change a few of firmware to get it up

Comment: Thank you for your advice to check the versions. I will check the firmware version as soon as I can work with the drone again and report back to you!

Comment: Thank you for your response. It made me check version again, which made me find out that the standard (master) branch for the iOS-Sample-App repository is the outdated version 3.1, which does not work with the newest Onboard SDK and the DJI Matrice 600. Version 3.3 worked perfectly for me. I'll post a reponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the standard (master) branch for the iOS-Sample-App repository is the old version 3.1, which did not work. Since there is no documentation on this I used this one because I did not know other versions exist until checking out the different branches.

In the end, version 3.3 worked best for me.
This is the link to the newest branch/version (3.4): https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-OSDK-iOS-App/tree/3.4