# DJI OSDK and OSDK-ROS 3.7 and 3.8 bug demo_flight_control take off and halt

Tags: dji-sdk

I`m facing issue that with OSDK-ROS 3.7 and 3.8, I could not run demo_flight_control sample correctly

After api auto taking off in the simulator, the drone just stuck there.  And there is command being published to the flight_control ENU topic.

The GPS based demo_mission has no issue. It can auto fly to the coordinate.

The hardware and firmware version I`m using is

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L729: Hardware = A3

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L730: Firmware = 3.3.8.47

The minimal sample for reproducing the issue is from here

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/tree/3.8/dji_sdk_demo/src

The flight_control issue is the same for OSDK (option b) and OSDK-ROS (default)

For Previous 3.3 3.5 3.6 I never encounter this before. I`ve send report to dev@dji.com. No response yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by myself

On  https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/tree/3.7  and 3.8 reqires  at least 1.7.6
[image]

But I can't find it 1.7.6 in the DJI assistant 2 firmware only 1.7.7 and 1.7.5. So I decided to use 1.7.7

[image]

But 1.7.7 does only work for GPS waypoint mission and does not support setpoint_generic based control

**So the solution is to use 1.7.5 to get both GPS based mission and ros topic based velocity control working.**

Below this version, the version control in the DJI system is hell with randomly labeled version. So you have to keep trial and error to get things up

---

### Below is DJI Email response. Pretty useless but will provide some cue for others to debug the similar issue

Bruce Cheung （DJI）

Dear Shenghai,

Thank you for contacting DJI.

We cannot reproduce the problem you mentioned by using A3 with OSDK3.7 and 3.8 
Can you try to take control authority  directly?  using /dji_sdk/sdk_control_authority
Also try publishing the /dji_sdk/flight_control_setpoint_ENUposition_yaw control command, do not use the sample.

Thank you for your understanding and support, hope you a delighted life.

Best Regards,
DJI SDK Support Team

---

Hi Bruce

I tried what you mentioned., use

```
  FIrst launch sdk.launch


 Then, rosservical call /dji_sdk/sdk_control_authority 1



And write a simple empty C++ script to publish to    /dji_sdk/flight_control_setpoint_generic.
```

The result is the same. the drone is not moving in the DJI assistant2 simulator.

My theory is the A3 firmware version might be too high on GitHub  https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/tree/3.7

it says 3.7 and 3.8 support

A3/A3 Pro   1.7.6.0
But I can't find it 1.7.6 in the DJI assistant 2 firmware only 1.7.7 and 1.7.5. So I decided to use 1.7.7

Will this be the issue?

Its 11 pm in Singapore, I ll take two videos of sample and custom method tmr morning. I`ll upload the video to youtube.  you can see from there.

Regards

Shenghai Yuan